# Google Translate API - html document translation

Tags: php, wordpress, google-translate

I'm trying out Google Translate API to translate my blog. Access to the API works, I can send text and get the appropriate translation but whenever I send larger documents with HTML in it, I don't get any answer from the API anymore.

I'm using PHP to send the query with the code below and I'm extracting posts from my wordpress site (= it only extracts the content between the body tags).

PHP CODE:

```
function translation ($text,$origin,$destination)
    {
        $apiKey = 'MY_API_KEY';
        $url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key='.$apiKey.'&q='.rawurlencode($text).&source='.$origin.'&target='.$destination;
        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($handle);                 
        $responseDecoded = json_decode($response, true);
        curl_close($handle);
        print_r($response);
        print_r($responseDecoded);
    }
```

If I feed the variables with:

```
$text: "hello world" 
$origin: "en"
$destination: "fr"
```

I works without any problem.

If I feed $text with html, I don't get any answer from the API, not even an error message. I checked the documentation and saw this: https://cloud.google.com/translate/markup

I tried to add the body/header part but it doesn't work but I hope I'm not obliged to add this into my code because this would require a major change on all the pages to make it work.

Do you have any idea of how I could make this work?

**UPDATE:**
If I use substr in PHP to reduce the size of $text, I get it translated up to around 5200 chars, above this, I do not get anything any more.

Thanks!

Laurent

Comment: If you look at the Translate API documentation - https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/translate , you can pass the `format` parameter to specify whether you are sending plain text or html. Have you tried defining this in your post request?

Comment: @PhilippSh Thanks! yes, I did, html is by default but I tried it with the parameter too. It's really a volume problem because the same pages broken in chunks of 5000 chars is working while if I send it in one chunck, it doesn't work. I cannot imagine that Google has this kind of limitation and it's not mentioned anywhere in their documentation.

Comment: This article here says that it is recommended to send less than 5000 characters per request -https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions

Comment: Hello @PhilippSh thanks, I didn't see this one, this confirms my findings. It's a pity they don't take more than 5000 chars as most of the web pages today have more than 5000 chars. Anyway..there is no way around it, problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is recommending to send [less than 5000 characters per request](https://cloud.google.com/translate/faq#technical_questions). In your case you would need to develop a function that splits the text into chunks of size less than 5000 characters (HTML tags included) and send them in separate requests. However, please be aware that there are also limits with respect to [characters sent per 100 seconds](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#content) and [requests sent per 100 seconds](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas#request_quotas).